# How to install/deploy artifacts compiled by make-maven-plugin

Tags: c, maven-2, makefile

I'm using the [make-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cbuild-parent/cbuild-plugin-parent/make-maven-plugin/) to build a software written in C with Maven. My goal is to automatically install and deploy the source tarball AND the binary artifact to the Maven repository when I run `mvn install` and `mvn deploy`. My current pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>make-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <destDir>${project.build.directory}/dest</destDir>
          <workDir>${basedir}</workDir>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>package</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>make-dist</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skipDist>false</skipDist>
              <sourceArchive>${project.name}-${project.version}.tar.bz2</sourceArchive>
              <sourceArchivePath>${project.build.directory}</sourceArchivePath>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I package the project then I have the following files in the target directory:

- myProject-2.0.bin (The compiled binary artifact)
- myProject-2.0.tar.bz2 (The source tar ball)

When running `mvn install` then the created source tar ball and the POM file is installed to the local maven repository. How can I tell Maven to also install the binary file? I don't want to copy it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the binary file as an artifact using [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html)